# F# script to application

Tags: f#

I have written two small scripts,

First one maintains a dictionary of current stock prices for a set of securities. I am using recursion to listen to a named pipe. Whenever there is something available on the name pipe, it updates the security price and goes right back and start listening to the pipe.

The second one periodically reads the stock price of some security from the price cache of the first program and performs come calculation.

But I have no idea how to make these two programs communicate. I somehow need to make my second programs start the first program and let it run in the background and get the price whenever it needs it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you,
-Sudaly

Answer (score 3):

Do they have to be separate programs/scripts?

If not, I would put them in the same program and use async/agents to run the two tasks.

Here's a starter-blog for that strategy:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112140802/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/02/15/async-and-parallel-design-patterns-in-f-part-3-agents.aspx)

Basically one agent just sits in a loop: async read from pipe, update price

The other agent sits in a loop: sleep for some time, read price and do calculation.  Alternatively this could just be the synchronous 'main program' loop.

(Depending on data structure, you may or may not need coordination to deal with one agent reading while other is updating.)

Actually, you don't even need an agent, can just have async that runs in background.  Something like

```
// first script
let mutable lastPrice = 0.0
async {
    while true do
        let! nextval = namedPipe.AsyncRead()
        lastPrice <- nextVal
} |> Async.Start 
// second script
while true do
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    printfn "%f" (calc lastPrice)
```

if that helps.

Comment: Well... they don’t have to be separate programs at the moment. But in the future I may have to write some other application that could use the price cache. So I like to keep only one instance of the price cache program and be able to refer by multiple programs. 

But for now, your solution is sufficient. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways.

1. .Net Remoting
2. Pipes
3. Text files on disk
4. intermediary service (web or local)
5. wcf